# Error in importing pandas in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.
Whenever I try to import pandas in Jupyter Notebook, I get this error.
I have tried several ways to resolve this issue available on internet.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I also got error while installing pandas in Jupyter notebook:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pandas
  Building wheel for pandas (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command /snap/jupyter/6/bin/python /snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpecqq53bt:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-37
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/pandas
  copying pandas/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/pandas
```

```
 check.warn(importable)
  error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory: 'gcc'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
  Running setup.py clean for pandas

Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I try to install pandas using ubuntu terminal but got these warnings.
pip3 install pandas
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2022.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (1.19.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.16.0)

Comment: Have you tried running in a cell inside the notebook where you want to import pandas, `%pip install pandas`? Try that and then if it runs & installs, restart the kernel, and then try `import pandas as pd` in the same notebook.

Comment: @Wayne 
"pip install pandas''  
Collecting pandas  
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/f0  /f99700ef327e51d291efdf4a6de29e685c4d198cbf8531541fc84d169e0e/pandas-1.3.5.tar.gz  
  Installing build dependencies ... done  
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done  
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done  
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3; platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64" and python_version < "3.10" in /home/chetan/snap/jupyter/common/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.21.6)  
Collecting pytz>=2017.3 (from pandas)

Comment: continued.....
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/ac/92f998fc52a70afd7f6b788142632afb27cd60c8c782d1452b7466603332/pytz-2022.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl   
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.0)     
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.12.0)   
Building wheels for collected packages: pandas   
  Building wheel for pandas (PEP 517) ... error

Comment: Building wheel for pandas (PEP 517) ... error    
  ERROR: Complete output from command /snap/jupyter/6/bin/python /snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpfxkhg9aj:    
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel     
  running build   
  running build_py

Comment: It's very specific, it needs to be `%pip install pandas` in the Jupyter notebook cell. Also your stuff looks outdated. When did you install Python? I'd suggest installing the Anaconda distribution or at least miniconda and then using conda to install Pandas. Using `%conda install -c anaconda pandas` inside a notebook running in the enviornment you want to work. You can also use `conda install -c anaconda pandas` when you are in the environment.